# what does the two table Users and auth_user in Django are for?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin, django-database

I know the functionality of `User model` in `Django`. but when I `syncdb`, I see of the many `auth_* tables` created, there is one `auth_user`. There is yet another `User` table.
There are differences between them in the columns. I am attaching them here. when I add a new User it gets stored in auth_user table, but the `User` table is empty. so what is this `User` table for (why is it created if it empty) and where it is useful. why is it not populated?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `auth_user` table keeps track of registered users for Django's included auth system.

The `Users` table is not created by Django. It must be created by a third-party Django app you are using, or it is created through some other process entirely.